# How to solve the matrix equation $ABA^{-1}=C$ with $\operatorname{Tr}(A)=a$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have the following matrix equation:
$$ABA^{-1}=C$$
with $B$ and $C$ given and $A$ unknown.
The constraint on $A$ is $\operatorname{Tr}(A)=a$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}$.
The matrices are $N\times N$.

Comment: Such $A$ does not always exist. For instance, when $B=C=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$, every matrix that commutes with $B$ (hence $AB=BA=CA$) must be of the form $A=\pmatrix{x&y\\ 0&x}$. So, if $A$ is invertible, $x$ cannot be zero and $A$ has nonzero trace. Thus, when $a=0$, there is no solution.

Comment: @user1551: and when $a\ne 0$?

Comment: Well first such an $A$ exists only if $B$ and $C$ are similar in the sense that they have the same eigenvalues (which is, however, not a sufficient condition). If you had an $A$ satisfying $ABA^{-1}=C$ with non-zero trace, then obviously you can scale the matrix $A$ with any scalar $\alpha\neq 0$ and you still get that $(\alpha A)B(\alpha A)^{-1}=C$ while $\alpha A$ can achieve any nonzero value.

Comment: The equation may still be unsolvable if $a\ne0$. Consider $B=\pmatrix{1\\ &2}$ and $C=\pmatrix{2\\ &1}$. The only solutions are $A=\pmatrix{0&y\\ z&0}$, which is traceless. So, if $a\ne0$, there is no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the equation as:
$$ 
AB = CA
$$
and using the Kronecker product matrix equation identity
$$
\mathrm{vec}(AXB) = (B^T\otimes A)\mathrm{vec}(X)
$$
you get
$$
(B^T\otimes I_N - I_N\otimes C)\mathrm{vec}(A) = 0,
$$
where $I_N$ is an $N\times N$ identity matrix. Together with the trace constraint you have $N^2+1$ equations and $N^2$ unknowns so the existence of the solution is not always guaranteed. For $\alpha = 0$, if the solution exists it would be any element of the null space of the matrix
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c} B^T\otimes I_N - I_N\otimes C \\ \mathrm{vec}(I_N)^T \end{array}\right].
$$

Comment: How do you guarantee that $A$ is invertible?

Comment: The initial matrix equation includes the inverse of A, so A has to be invertible for the equation to make sense.

Comment: No. The set of equations $ABA^{-1}=C,\ \mathrm{tr}(A)=\alpha$ is not equivalent to $AB=CA,\ \mathrm{tr}(A)=\alpha$. For instance, consider $AIA^{-1}=0,\ \mathrm{tr}(A)=0$. The first equation here "includes the inverse of $A$", but it has no solution. Yet $AI=0A,\ \mathrm{tr}(A)=0$ has a unique solution $A=0$, which is noninvertible.

Comment: Agree, but in this case I wouldn't regard $A=0$ as solution. The expression $ABA^{-1}$ is not defined for $A=0$. That's my interpretation. If you write $A^{-1}$ then $A$ has to be invertible, otherwise the problem is not well defined.

Comment: Adding to the above, if $B=I$, then $C=I$ as well. This gives $B^T\otimes I_N - I_N \otimes C = 0$. So any matrix $A$ that has trace $0$, will be a solution. $A=0$ is not unique and you can have invertible $A$ with 0 trace.

Comment: The point is, that the system of equations $AB=CA,\mathrm{tr}(A)=\alpha$ is solvable doesn't make $A$ invertible. Let's return to my first example in the comment below the OP's question, where $B=C=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$ and $\alpha=0$. **All** solutions $A$ for $AB=CA,\mathrm{tr}(A)=0$ are noninvertible.

Comment: The question is whether you are willing to accept as an answer a matrix $A$ which is not invertible, in an problem that explicitly involves $A^{-1}$. I'm not, but it's a rather technical issue in my opinion, or the problem should state that explicitly. However, also note that in the case you describe, according to my derivation the matrix should belong to the null space of $$\left[\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right],$$ which gives exactly the same characterization as the one you get.

Comment: It is IMHO stated explicitly enough. I don't think this is a technical issue. A solution simply cannot exist if B and C are not similar.